# How can I assign a variable to a query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

For my project I need to check if some variables are empty and if they are then:

1. The user gets a custom view with a message on which variable is missing.
2. The developer/me must be able to see the query which was sent to check if there are no failure's in the query.

My question is how can I assign a variable (for example $checkQuery) to my query so that it has all the values and I can check it within the error log.

**Query**

```
function createUser($data){
    $this->firstname    = $data['firstname'];
    $this->lastname     = $data['surname1'].' '.$data['surname2'];
    $this->address      = $data['adres'];
    $this->zipcode      = $data['zipcode'];
    $this->mail         = $data['mail'];
    $this->phonenumber  = $data['phonenumber'];
    

    $this->db->insert('User',$this);
   
    //Check if the change was succesfull
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

**Function for errorLog**

```
function errorLog($var){ //Get the variable that you have passed from your helper  
    $mail = "Email was empty";
    $firstname ="Firstname was empty";
    
    if($var == 'mail') //Change the error function based on what has been passed
    {
        return log_message('error', $mail); //Here use the return type
    }
    if($var == 'firstname')
    {
        return log_message('error', $firstname); //Here use the return type
    }
}
```

The view for the user is done which I've done with just a simple array but the only thing I see at the moment is just if firstname or email is was empty.
So is it possible to use a PHP variable in which I can assign the submitted values and can put these into my error log preferably using `log_message`

Comment: I guess you're using a form to submit the data to be inserted? Why don't you use a form validation technique (client-side + server-side)? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html - Also check `$this->db->last_query()` method for sending debug data to the developer.

Comment: Yes I am using a form to submit the data to be inserted, the thing I want is attaching the submitted data to a variable and putting that in my log file if there is an error. I will read through the guide and maybe that has my solution